# Where to save custom metadata?

Tags: dspace, dublin-core

I want to track some items submitted by a custom software to DSpace. Saving the ID (and maybe the URL) is enough.

Where do you think I can put this data? Has Dublin Core any term/property for this? Should I create a custom schema?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can browse your metadata field registry to determine if an appropriate metadata field exists in Dublin Core.  The folks on the DSpace Community list (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/dspace-community) may be able to offer advise on how to make the best use of a given field.

If you do not see an appropriate element, it is appropriate to add your own local schema to the schema registry.  You can then define custom fields associated with that schema.

Once you have a custom schema, the import/export tools will write your custom metadata fields to a separate file (other than dublin_core.xml).